# White area in UITableViewCells iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad

What could possibly be causing this white area to show on my iPad simulator?

[image]

this is just a snippet of the table view and ONLY shows like this on the iPad. I've seen this before on my actual iPad app but only when the user selects the row it would highlight that weird white rectangle.

I'm about ready to submit a new build but afraid this will show like this on an actual iPad.. Anyone else seen this before?

Here's how my storyboard is set up:

[image]

And my folder/view hierarchy:

[image]

I realize I have a lot of views within views but I've never had this behavior before and the weird thing is i don't have any views that have the same dimensions as the mysterious white area..

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without knowing how your views are set up.  Please post the relevant sections of your code and Storyboard/Xib files (if using Interface Builder).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I updated my question with more screenshots.

Comment: It seems issue with your nameAge. Try to give a clearColor and if you have selection enabled on it set clearColor for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making the tableView background color and the cell background color **clear**.

[image]

[image]